# Ubiquiti UniFi gives a specific client a link-local address (169.254..) but DHCP works for other clients

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, ubiquiti, unifi

I have a weird problem. A single client in my home network keep getting a link-local address 169.254.., like 169.254.12.96.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address

https://community.ui.com/questions/Some-of-our-clients-get-an-169-254-adress/52e9d0ae-3b8e-4d96-b57e-7efeafa58649

List of Clients:

[image]

All firmware's are up to date.

[image]

DHCP is set to DHCP Mode: DHCP Server, DHCP Range is 192.168.1.6 to 192.168.1.254, DHCP Name Server is Auto, DHCP Lease Time is 86400 seconds and DHCP Gateway IP is Auto.

The client not working is a Windows 10 Enterprise laptop that works fine on other networks. I have tried forgetting the network, shut down the computer and connect again but always the same result. I have another Windows 10 Enterprise computer on the network that works without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by upgrading from UniFi Network Controller from `5.13.32` to `6.0.41` for Windows.

https://www.ui.com/download/unifi/

[image]